# Scale DB tables horizontally or vertically for new webapp? (MySQL / SQLite)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, web-applications

I'm planning on developing a simple portal for my vendors to login and see their sales history.  (This is for viewing purposes only so I'm looking at SQLite as the goto since there's no writing/locking issues at this time  - but it may become MySQL)

The nature of the portal means the user privileges will dictate that VendorA can see only VendorA's inventory/sales/etc and not anyone else's.  I'm new to webapp development so **I'm unsure if it's wiser to widen the database with tables so that each vendor gets new tables of their own tbl_vendor_a_sales, tbl_vendor_a_inventory, tbl_vendor_b_sales, etc.(?) or if I should have three big tables with all of my vendors' info stored there (tbl_orders, tbl_sales)?**

Each of the 300 vendors may have under 30,000 sales records and between 50-200k inventory records.

I'm thinking going the latter route of 2-3 big tables is optimal as I would have an easier time of doing any aggregate reporting if need be - but I'd still like to know I'm on the right track.

Comment: Why are you using SQLite for something like this? That's going to be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @tadman A read-only SQLite database will be slightly faster than MySQL. And I don't understand your remark about maintainability.

Comment: If I decide to charge Vendors for this service, don't I have to license MySQL?  It's definitely going to be read-only at this time - maybe down the road I'll add some writing, but right now I need to keep it simple to get this off the ground.

Comment: If you need aggregate reporting you will have a headache when you need to combine disparate databases into one table every time you want to run such a report. "Maintainablity":  If you have disparate database files/tables you have to make DDL changes in many places. There are (expensive--at least when compared to freeware) database solutions for this requirement. The term is Virtual Private Database.  Oracle and PostgreSQL Advanced Server (not the community edition) both offer robust ways to give users access only to the rows that belong to them so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning a table like this might make sense as an optimization, but as long as you do not have a performance problem, and have not actually measured a clear improvement, this would be premature.

If you are really concerned about security, you could put the data for each vendor into a separate database file, integrate the vendor logins with the web server's user management, and use file permissions to allow only one vendor to access each file.
However, it is unlikely that your web hosting allows you to do this.